# Deictic or not?

Tags: pronouns, deixis

Can these three italicized pronouns (line 2, 7 and 10): that's, he and them be classified as Deictic?  Proximal and anaphoric respectively.

“He was looking for some one else, you say – some one who was not you?”

“He was looking for little Miles.” A portentous clearness now possessed me. “*That’s* who he was looking for.”

“But how do you know?”

“I know, I know, I know!” My exaltation grew. “And you know, my dear!”

She did n’t deny this, but I required, I felt, not even so much telling as that. She took it up again in a moment. “What if *he* should see him?”

“Little Miles? That’s what he wants!”

She looked immensely scared again. “The child?”

“Heaven forbid! The man. He wants to appear to *them*.”

Comment: Credit the author (Henry James), link to source?

Comment: Turn of the Screw (1898) https://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/James/Turn_Screw.pdf   pg 43

Comment: You can possibly do this analytically.  But there's a good chance here that these pronouns are intentionally ambiguous, specifically, that they may mean different things to the speaker and the hearer.

Answer (score 2):

[chart][1]

This chart can be used for purposes  of analysis of the utterances. I am not prepared to do it. Too much work. Forgive me. The first step is to locate the speaker and think about how where the speaker is located in the space of the conversation, for instance. The pronouns are related to that speaker. "That's" (a deictic) who "he" is anaphoric. The that's refers to he. Them is also deictic. All pronouns are in English. But none appear that close to the speaker (proximal). i.e. That boy over there. In fact, we have no precise notion of proximity except in the discourse. Perhaps you have more context.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Deixis.png/600px-Deixis.png